# Pyomo: constraint with if statements

Tags: pyomo

I am currently trying to solve this problem. I need to maximize the profit of this company.

That s the code I currently have:

```
from pyomo.environ import *
from pyomo.opt import *
opt = solvers.SolverFactory("ipopt")
model = ConcreteModel()

model.x1 = Var(within=NonNegativeIntegers)
model.x2 = Var(within=NonNegativeIntegers)
model.y1 = Var(within=NonNegativeIntegers)
model.y2 = Var(within=NonNegativeIntegers)
model.b1 = Var(within=Boolean)
model.b2 = Var(within=Boolean)

model.c1 = Constraint(expr = model.x1 + model.x2 + model.y1 + model.y2 <=   7000)
model.c2 = Constraint(expr = 2*model.x1 + 2*model.x2 + model.y1 + model.y2 <= 10000)
model.c3 = Constraint(expr = model.x1  <= 2000)
model.c4 = Constraint(expr = model.x2 <= 1000)
model.c5 = Constraint(expr = model.y1 <= 2000)
model.c6 = Constraint(expr = model.y2 <= 3000)


model.z = Objective(expr= (150*model.x1 + 180*model.x2*model.b1 + 100*model.y1 + 110*model.y2*model.b2), sense=maximize)
results = opt.solve(model)
```

This is the code I tried to write for my constraint which is then only using the first slope as long as it does not exceed 2000 products:

```
def ObjRule(model):
 if model.x1 >= 2000:
     return model.b1==1
 if model.x2 >= 2000:
     return model.b2 == 1`
```

If someone would have a hint, how I could proceed that would be great.

thank you in advance,
Patrick

Answer (score 9):

In Pyomo, rules are not callbacks sent to a solver. They are called once for each index to obtain a static set of expressions. This set of expressions is what is sent to a solver. Any if-logic you use inside of rules should not involve the values of variables (unless it is based on the initial value of a variable, in which case you would wrap the variable in value() wherever you use it outside of the main expression that is returned).

If you want to model a piecewise function, you need to apply some kind of modeling trick to do so. In some cases this involves introducing discrete variables (see [examples](https://github.com/Pyomo/pyomo/tree/master/examples/pyomo/piecewise) for the Piecewise component), in other cases it does not (for instance when maximizing a piecewise function that can be expressed as the min of a finite number of affine functions).