# Change constraints based on variable value in Pyomo

Tags: pyomo

Is there a way of changing the values of a constraint as the solver is running?

Basically, I have a constraint that depends on the value of a variable. The problem is that the constraint is evaluated based on the initial value of the variable, but isn't updated as the variable changes.

Here's a simple example:

```
from pyomo.environ import *
from pyomo.opt import SolverFactory
import numpy as np

# Setup
model = ConcreteModel()
model.A = Set(initialize = [0,1,2])
model.B = Set(initialize = [0,1,2])
model.x = Var(model.A, model.B, initialize=0)

# A constraint that I'd like to keep updating, based on the value of x
def changing_constraint_rule(model, a):
    x_values = list((model.x[a, b].value for b in model.B))
    if np.max(x_values) == 0:
        return Constraint.Skip
    else:
        # Not really important what goes here, just as long as it updates the constraint list
        if a == 1 : return sum(model.x[a,b] for b in model.B) == 0
        else:       return sum(model.x[a,b] for b in model.B) == 1
model.changing_constraint = Constraint(model.A, rule = changing_constraint_rule)

# Another constraint that changes the value of x
def bounding_constraint_rule(model, a):
    return sum(model.x[a, b] for b in model.B) == 1
model.bounding_constraint = Constraint(
    model.A,
    rule = bounding_constraint_rule)

# Some objective function
def obj_rule(model):
    return(sum(model.x[a,b] for a in model.A for b in model.B))
model.objective = Objective(rule=obj_rule)

# Results
opt = SolverFactory("glpk")
results = opt.solve(model)
results.write()
model.x.display()
```

If I run `model.changing_constraint.pprint()` I can see that no constraints have been made, since the initial value of the variable `model.x` was set to 0.

If it's not possible to change the constraint values while solving, how could I formulate this problem differently to achieve what I'm looking for? I've read [this other post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40873161/pyomo-constraint-with-if-statements/40873728) but couldn't figure it out from the instructions.

Answer (score 1):

I am giving you the same answer in the other question by @Gabe:

> Any if-logic you use inside of rules should not involve the values of
>   variables (unless it is based on the initial value of a variable, in
>   which case you would wrap the variable in value() wherever you use it
>   outside of the main expression that is returned).

for example:
`model.x[a, b].value` should be `model.x[a, b].value()`

But still this might not give you the solution what you are looking for.

Comment: alas, I think it won't. Thanks for your reply anyway